# RichFaces tags are not executed

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-2.2

I have created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse Luna , using JSF 2.2, Jboss AS 7. The problem is that no button is rendered in browser from this code `<a4j:commandButton value="a4j button"></a4j:commandButton>` after I run the project. The same is true for `a4j:commandLink` for example.

I tried to modify `<url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>` into `<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>` (found something like this on the internet) but no result.
Hitting `Ctrl Space` on `<a4j:` pops a list of tags so i guess richfaces is properly installed.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
        xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <rich:panel>
                <a4j:commandButton value="a4j button"></a4j:commandButton>
            </rich:panel>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

web.xml file:

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">`

    <display-name>TestProject</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml file:

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
</faces-config>
```

Comment: Are you implying that `<rich:xxx>` work fine?

Comment: `rich` does not work also.

Comment: How exactly did you install RichFaces?

Comment: Why don't you have a head region in your page (as in `<h:head/>`)?

Comment: I have installed jboss tools from eclipse marketplace which it comes with richfaces i think. I did not add any richfaces libraries to my project. I can pop the tag list of `a4j` and `rich` so I think it recognizes RichFaces.. Am i wrong..?

Comment: @kolossus I tried with  <h:head></h:head> but it has no result. In this example I forgot to insert the <h:head>